# Getting YouTube Video File Location With API3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I was wondering if it was possible to get the location of the file of the video with the new API?

I don't want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EikPnyG7cfc

I want the actual video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the YouTube API doesn't provide this because YouTube doesn't want people hotlinking their videos outside of their player and ad system. You'll have to look for something outside the API. Note this appears to be prohibited in their TOS:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, since your "I don't want" link points to a YouTube video, and not API or location information.

Every video contains a [`recordingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails) object which contains a string description of the video, as well as the geolocation information associated with the video.

If this is not what you are looking for, you could potentially check the [`fileDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#fileDetails) object on the video which contains a `recordingLocation` on from the file metadata.

I seem to have misunderstood your question:

You can use a tool such as youtube-dl to download the mp4 file from YouTube.

Install youtube-dl using a package manager or the [installation guide](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation).  Running the program with no parameters gets the highest quality video and audio for download:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EikPnyG7cfc
```

Example output:

```
➜  ~  youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=EikPnyG7cfc
[youtube] EikPnyG7cfc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] EikPnyG7cfc: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] EikPnyG7cfc: Extracting video information
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: Soda Stereo - Ella Usó Mi Cabeza Como un Revólver-EikPnyG7cfc.f135.mp4
[download] 100% of 17.82MiB in 00:00
[download] Destination: Soda Stereo - Ella Usó Mi Cabeza Como un Revólver-EikPnyG7cfc.f251.webm
[download] 100% of 4.25MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "Soda Stereo - Ella Usó Mi Cabeza Como un Revólver-EikPnyG7cfc.mkv"
Deleting original file Soda Stereo - Ella Usó Mi Cabeza Como un Revólver-EikPnyG7cfc.f135.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file Soda Stereo - Ella Usó Mi Cabeza Como un Revólver-EikPnyG7cfc.f251.webm (pass -k to keep)
➜  ~
```

Comment: I was talking about a link to the video that is embeded in the site, not the page that has the video in it. Something with the extension .mp4 for example

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood your question.  You can get the MP4 link of a YouTube video using tools like [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), however this breaks YouTube's terms of service.

Comment: Ok, thank you, yes, I tried that but it's too complicated for me.

Comment: @user3808307 Edited my answer to add steps to download the video file with youtube-dl.

Comment: Thanks, I will check to see if I can get it running. Else I will ask in stackoverflow again :)